# Get frequency of occurrence of a character value in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this:

```
col1  col2  cole3 
abc   def    xzy
lmk   qwe    abc
def   lmk    xzy
xzy    abc   qwe
```

The three columns hold character datatype values.
Across the 3 columns I have 5 unique values: abc, def, xzy, lmk and qwe.
What I need is a count of number of times each of these values appears in the whole dataframe.

```
abc 3
qwe 2
def 2
xzy 3
lmk 2
```

All the count() and aggregate functions only work column-wise and when I unlist, it doesnt seem to work either.

Any suggestions for functions that I can use?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like that (assuming that your previous data frame is called df1):

```
data <- c(df1$col1, df1$col2, df1$col3)
table(data)
```

And it gives you desired values. Make sure your data in df1 are characters not factors.

Comment: perfect!! Thank you so much. I was making it so complicated with group_by()and unlist() and what not.

Comment: Just a follow-up question. How to find the frequency of one particular value, like for example "abc" across the three columns?

Comment: I think you should do it by extraction operator `[ ]`

Comment: e.g `table(data)[1]` will be the value for "abc" character

Comment: No, i mean, If I am not using table() then? Like a string match except for character value and get the number of matches

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explain?

Comment: For example, if my dataframe was called df1. Then without using table(), I want to find the number of occurrences of the value lmk. Like using: filter(df1, col1=="lmk" | col2== "lmk " | col3== "lmk") Something like this.

Comment: Simply `length(df1 == "lmk")` that's all

Comment: I am getting a count thats different from what I got using table()

Comment: Sorry. It should be: `length(which(df1 == "lmk))`

Answer (score -2):

You can use an aggregate function with 'union all' - make sure you use 'union all', not just 'union'.

Let us assume that your table is called tmpcol with columns col1, col2, and col3...

```
select value, sum(cnt)
from (
 select col1 as value, count(*) as cnt
 from tmpcol
 group by col1

  union all

 select col2 as value, count(*) as cnt
 from tmpcol
 group by col2

  union all

 select col3 as value, count(*) as cnt
 from tmpcol
 group by col3
) dataset
group by value;
```

Comment: That's fine if they were writing in SQL, but this question is tagged R and not SQL